# L2TP and IPSEC from Windows XP: Where do I put the IPSEC group name?

Tags: ipsec, l2tp

I'm completely new to networking, but need to setup a VPN. I have a linksys router and have gone through and set it up to use IPSEC and have setup a group name, user, password and pre-shared key. But I can't seem to connect via Windows XP.

One thing I've noticed is there is no spot I can find to enter the group name. Is there somewhere specific I should be entering this?

When I try to connect without it I get: Error 789: The L2TP connection attempt failed because the security layer encountered an error during initial negotiations.

If I retry I get error 792: The L2TP connection attempt failed because security negotiation timed out.

I'm not at work to check the router logs of what happened. (have to do that tomorrow.) Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the *Properties* of the VPN connection, there should be a *Security* tab. The *Type of VPN* at the top should be set to L2TP/IPsec. Below this dropdown, you should see a *Advanced Settings* button which will allow you to enter a preshared key for authentication. You should put the group name there.

Comment: You wrote to put the group name in the field for the preshared key for authentication. How do you enter it there when you also have a preshared key? Or do you mean that there is another field next to the preshared key parameter field?