# Windows 11 L2TP and IPSEC: Where to set the IpSec group

Tags: windows, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

**First of all:**

- I know : [L2TP and IPSEC from Windows XP: Where do I put the IPSEC group name?](https://serverfault.com/questions/78533/l2tp-and-ipsec-from-windows-xp-where-do-i-put-the-ipsec-group-name) exists, but **the answer is incorrect and is not working on Windows 11** (please do not duplicate this topic by linking that one, it's 13 years old).
- And: [L2TP and IPSEC from Windows 11: Where do I put the IPSEC group name?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1107707/l2tp-and-ipsec-from-windows-11-where-do-i-put-the-ipsec-group-name) was closed pointing on the first topic without addressing the question as well. (@Jan Janiszewski)

We need to connect to an already setup VPN using IPSec Id / Group name:

**VPN Data:**

- VPN type: "IPSec" or "IPSec Xauth PSK"
- Name / Description: Individualized name for the connection
- Server address / Server: `45.123.123.12`
- IPSec ID / Group name: `thegroup.name`
- IPSec key / Shared secret: `sharedkey`
- Username / Account: `user.name`
- Password: Password of the user `user.name`

**The input doesn't shows up on our machines:**

- OS Name  Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
- Version  10.0.22000 Build 22000

Is there a register key or anything to setup first?

Is there any VPN Client able to fit the requirement and that could be use by an entreprise ?

Does anybody already find a solution to this problem on **Windows 11**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only IPsec related Windows built-in VPN clients are:

- IPsec IKEv2
- L2TP/IPsec

Windows has no built-in IPsec IKEv1 Xauth (Cisco-style) VPN client.

Some people recommend the Shrew Soft VPN Client for Windows, in particular the Standard edition which can be used for either personal or commercial use:

- https://www.shrew.net/software

see the following doc on how to configure the Shrew Soft VPN client for Mutual PSK + XAuth :

- https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/smb/routers/cisco-rv-series-small-business-routers/Configuring_Shrew_Soft_VPN_Client_with_the_RV160_and_RV260.pdf